# Difference between apex:composition and apex:component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Please let me know the difference between **apex:composition** and **apex:component**

Help is much appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Composition:** An area of a page that includes content from a second template page. Template pages are Visualforce pages that include one or more  components. The  component names the associated template, and provides body for the template's  components with matching  components. Any content outside of an  component is not rendered

This is Page which define template and use composition element

```
<!-- Page: composition -->
<!-- This page acts as the template. Create it first, then the page below.  --> 
<apex:page>
    <apex:outputText value="(template) This is before the header"/><br/>
    <apex:insert name="header"/><br/>
    <apex:outputText value="(template) This is between the header and body"/><br/>
    <apex:insert name="body"/>
</apex:page>
```

This is Page which define elements of composition

```
<!-- Page: page -->
<apex:page>
    <apex:composition template="composition">
        <apex:define name="header">(page) This is the header of mypage</apex:define>
        <apex:define name="body">(page) This is the body of mypage</apex:define>
    </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

**Component:** Components are reusable section of UI. For ex. Header, footer, widgets etc.

This is Page:

```
<apex:page>
    <c:myComponent myValue="My component's value" borderColor="red" />
</apex:page>
```

This is Component Definition:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="myValue" description="This is the value for the component."
        type="String" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="borderColor" description="This is color for the border." type="String" required="true"/>
    <h1 style="border:{!borderColor}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!myValue}"/>
    </h1>
</apex:component>
```

So, you can use various section of Composition at various places but you will have to use whole component at given time.

Answer (score 1):

**apex:component** are discrete standalone items, when we use a component it will fetch all component into a page where we used it.

But in **apex:composition** we have **apex:define** to define something into a composition and we can use it by **apex:insert**.
So it will not include whole **apex:composition** but only provides body for the template's **apex:insert** components with matching **apex:define** component